# Azure china kubernetes cluster monitoring

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-log-analytics, azure-china

Azure Rest of world Kubernetes service cluster logs can be monitored in Azure log analytics workspace. How can we monitor  **china azure**(.cn) Kubernetes service cluster ?
i need to check the health of aks china cluster(like health of pods, nodes, cpu , memory.)

Comment: I'm not aware if Azure Monitor works in china, if it doesnt - you can use prometheus to monitor your AKS cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure china started services for Log analytics Workspace. So,my issue resolved.